# Trazer o id PHP na consulta do autocomplete do JqueryUI

Tags: php, jquery-ui

Tenho esta estrutura:

```js
$(function($) {
  $( "#cliente" ).autocomplete({
    source: '../php/search_clientes.php'
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" value="" name="cliente" id="cliente" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Onde o "search_clientes.php" é:

```html
<?php
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/
 include "../../Conexao/config.php";
 mysqli_select_db($config, $database_config);
 mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8");
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/

 //get search term
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

 $sql_1 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT * FROM tb_agenda WHERE nome_razao LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND tipo_contato = '12' ORDER BY nome_razao ASC LIMIT 10") or die(mysqli_error($config));

 if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_1) <= '0'){
  //echo "$erro"; 
 }else{
  while($r_sql_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_1)){
   $cliente = $r_sql_1['nome_razao'];
   $data[]  = $cliente;
  }
 }

 //return json data
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

É possível, alguma forma de trazer o id em algum input hidden, ou trazer o id do PHP de alguma forma?

Encontrei isso, mas depois de um dia tentando, assumo que preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#cliente" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        /*esta requisição ira consultar  somente o nome do cliente */
        $.ajax({
            url: '../php/search_clientes.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                parametro: /*SERIA BOM ENVIAR UM NOVO PARAMENTRO PARA ESPECIFICAR QUER ESTA CONSULTANDO SOMENTE O NOME*/
                term: $('#cliente').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
               response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#cliente").val( ui.item.nome );
        carregarDados();//na função CARREGADADOS() é que você irá pegar a ID em uma nova  requisição
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#cliente").val( ui.item.nome );
        return false;
    }
})
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a><b>Nome: </b>" + item.nome )
    .appendTo( ul );
};

function carregarDados(){
    var busca = $('#cliente').val();
    if(busca != "" && busca.length >= 3){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../php/search_clientes.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                acao: 'consulta',
                parametro: $('#cliente').val()
            },
            success: function( data ) {
               $('#INPUT_HIDDEN').val(data);//AQUI VOCE PODE ARMAZENAR O RETORNO EM QUALQUER LUGAR OU VARIAVEL
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Não fiz a parte do PHP, porém você terá que adicionar um outra função só para consultar a ID e retornar Assim que estiver selecionado o nome do cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado por hora.

No PHP, posso fazer:

```html
<?php
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/
 include "../../Conexao/config.php";
 mysqli_select_db($config, $database_config);
 mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8");
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/

 //get search term
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

 $sql_1 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT * FROM tb_agenda WHERE nome_razao LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND tipo_contato = '12' ORDER BY nome_razao ASC LIMIT 10") or die(mysqli_error($config));

 if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_1) <= '0'){
  //echo "$erro"; 
 }else{
  while($r_sql_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_1)){
   $id_cliente = $r_sql_1['id'];
      $cliente    = $r_sql_1['nome_razao'];
   $data[]     = $id_cliente . " - " . $cliente;
  }
 }

 //return json data
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Nisso tenho uma variável com o id.

Mas no Jquery, "parametro: /*SERIA BOM ENVIAR UM NOVO PARAMENTRO PARA ESPECIFICAR QUER ESTA CONSULTANDO SOMENTE O NOME*/".
Esse novo parêmetro é o ID?

Desculpe pela ignorância, mas realmente eu nunca tinha mexido no avançado do autocomplete.